# Fetching Mongodb data to Node and React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I am fetching my mongodb data to react with nodejs
I have fetched the data from mongodb

```
const express = require('express');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/', (err, db) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err)

    app.listen(3000, () => {
        console.log('app working on 3000')
    });

    let dbase = db.db("Forecast");

    app.get('/data', (req, res, next) => {
        dbase.collection('Forecast_collection').find({}).toArray((err, results) => {
            res.send(results);

        });
    });


});
```

[image: MONGODB]

This is the form of data I received in Mongodb

[image: localhost]

MY localhost data

I am not getting it in a formatted way

**How should I get this data to react JS can anyone help me with the react code as I want to display latest temperature and humidity as per time it should change**

Comment: Your question doesn't have any React code in it. What are you needing help with, specifically? See [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I can't see any problem with the result? What were you expect to see in the response?

Comment: I am not able to get data to react app as I am new to this if anyone can help me just to built the code to excess this data on localhost:3000